# Sharing a database over the local network

Tags: sql-server, networking

We have some plate nesting software at work which I use daily.

Recently, I thought I'd try to get the shared database up and working so the boys in the workshop could use the software on another PC (they could use the plate lists etc and as they use materials its updated on my computer as well).

My PC is running Windows 7, and the workshop computer is running Windows 8.1.

Here are the instructions that the software author gives:

- [ProNest® 2012 and Shared Network Databases](http://downloads.hyperthermcam.com/pronest/RelNotes/ProNest%202012%20and%20Shared%20Network%20Databases%2010_00_01.pdf) (pdf)

Where it says to add users to the local group, I can't see the workshop computer to add it. Essentially only user accounts on the Windows 7 machine can be added, and if i try from the workshop computer it does the same thing.

After spending hours reading forums etc I have found that the above instructions assume you have active directory (which we don't have).

The version of SQL is SQL Server 2008 (MSSQL10).

Can I somehow share this database over the network between 2 computers?

The contents of the ini file are:

```
[Database Connection]
Provider=SQLNCLI10
Initial Catalog=ProNest10
Integrated Security=SSPI
Data Source=.\MTCSOFTWARE
[Database History Connection]
Provider=SQLNCLI10
Initial Catalog=PN10History
Integrated Security=SSPI
Data Source=.\MTCSOFTWARE
```

Any input/web links on possibly getting this working would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First off check to see if your shop computer and office computer are on the same domain/homegroup.  You'll at the very least need to be on the same network/subnet in order to join them together.

It *sounds* like the computers are not on the same network or at the very least not visible to you.  On your office computer, create the GROUP.  Only when the computers can see/talk to each other can you add users from that machine to the GROUP so they can access the database.

Comment: Thank you for the reply,

Yes both computers are on the same home group and can share files/folders.

In the ini file where I'm suppose to change the "data source" to point to the "database server" can I enter IP address's or network links in there?

Cheers

Comment: Yes that should be the case.

`1. Use notepad.exe to open the file:
..\Program Files\Hypertherm CAM\ProNest 2012\mtcmrp.ini
2. Under the Database Connection section, modify the Data Source value to point to
<name>\MTCSOFTWARE on the database server.
3. Under the Database History Connection section, modify the Data Source value to point to
<name>\MTCSOFTWARE on the database server.
(Substitute the name of the database server computer for <name>)`
I don't know if they are looking for a full UNC path or what, that part is not made particularly clear.  I'd suspect **\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\MTCSOFTWARE**

Comment: Great, i will try this today and report back. Thanks for your reply.